# Replacing a specific char in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Attendance` and columns called `attendanceStatus` and `CourseID`. The `attendanceStatus` column is a text type because I wish to be able to change each `0` to a `1` at any given stage. The data is filled with `0`'s but I wish to change the last `0` in the string to a `1`. The data contains 18 `0`'s, so it would be the 18th character that I would need to change.

I feel like I have come close with this but I am willing to listen to changing it completely if I am not close.

```
UPDATE Attendance
SET attendanceStatus REPLACE = (attendanceStatus, '0', '1')
WHERE CourseID like '2%';
```

I realize that this code changes all of the 0's to 1's and I only wish to change the 18th 0.

Comment: `update attendance set attendancestatus = concat(substring(attendancestatus,1,17),'1') where courseID lke '2%' and attendancestatus like '%0';`

Comment: Given this type of requirement, it seems like that column contains more than one distinct value. If you want to change the value of a single character, at a certain position, within a character column (in MySQL table), the solution to that is going to involve the **`SUBSTRING`** function (to extract the parts of the string you want to leave unmodified), and the **`CONCAT`** function (to concatenate the parts of the string back together). A more robust solution is likely also going to invoke the **`CHAR_LENGTH`** function, to perform sanity checks. And those expressions are gonna be fugly.

Answer (score 8):

You are storing attendance status using the wrong method.  Although I can appreciate why you would store these in a string, it is really cumbersome.  How are you going to answer:  How many students attended for at least 10 days?  How many students were around on day 6?  How many students were absent for three days in a row?

The correct method is to have a separate row for each "day" (I'm not sure what the correct units are).  It would be something like:

```
create table StudentAttendance (
    StudentAttendanceId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    StudentId int not null references Student(StudentId),
    CourseId int not null references Courses(CourseId),
    Date date,
    status char(1),
    constraint unq_scd unique (StudentId, CourseId, Date)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Attendance
SET attendanceStatus = CONCAT( SUBSTRING(attendanceStatus, 
                                         1, 
                                         CHAR_LENGTH (attendanceStatus) - 1
                                        ), 
                               '1' )
WHERE CourseID like '2%';
```